# Does Minecraft use any open source Java libraries apart from the JDK?

Tags: java

I'm interested in writing games in Java and wondered if Minecraft is written purely using the standard JDK or whether it uses open source (or commercial for that matter) libraries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Minecraft uses the [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) library for graphics and sound.

Comment: Also found that it uses a sound library paulscode.sound from  http://www.paulscode.com/docs/SoundSystem/paulscode/sound/libraries/LibraryJavaSound.html and LZMA

Comment: LZMA is a component of LWJGL. Not sure about paulscode.sound.

Comment: I see. As for paulscode.sound I saw it was loaded by the JVM using JVisualVM.

Answer (score 5):

It uses Java Game Controller API `jinput` as well from [here](http://java.net/projects/jinput)